# sphinx autodoc and autosummary with pyproject.ml

Tags: python-sphinx, autodoc, pyproject.toml

In the docs

https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/tutorial/describing-code.html?highlight=pyproject.toml#including-doctests-in-your-documentation

says

> Note
>
> An alternative to changing the sys.path variable is to create a pyproject.toml file and make the code installable, so it behaves like any other Python library. However, the sys.path approach is simpler.

and nothing more.

I can't make that work and I devoted at least 6 hours to this. Could you point to (or provide) a working (toy) example using `autodoc`, `autosummary` and `pyproject.toml` that I can reproduce?

Comment: Show what you currently have (`pyproject.toml`, etc.) and what the symptoms of the issue are.